# Double integrals - polar coordinate system

Tags: integration

I need to find a volume of an object bounded by two planes:

$$x^{2}+y^{2}-z^{2}=0$$
$$x^{2}+y^{2}=2y$$

This is the upside-down cone with the r=1 circle as a base.

To find a volume of this cone I want to use polar coordinate system, and now the question comes - what should I consider as radius here?

I mean, the circle is not in the center of the coordinate system, so the radius won't vary from 0 to 1 as it would if the circle was in the center...How does it work?

Comment: Those are *not* planes...not even close: the first one is an elliptical hyperboloid, the second one is a simple infinite cylinder (all this in three dimensional space)

Comment: Thanks, but still, how will the radius look like if the circle is not in the middle of the coordinate system? :P

Comment: If you just wanna find the volume bounded those two surfaces, then the volume is infinite unless you have a bound on the range of $z$.

Comment: Complete the square to figure out the radius. You have $$ x^2+y^2=2y\Rightarrow x^2 + (y^2-2y+1)-1=0\Rightarrow x^2+(y-1)^2 = 1^2$$ so you have a cylinder of radius 1.

Answer (score 3):

As @Shuhao Cao noted we need a range for $z$, otherwise the volume as you see below is infinite. I assume that the solid volume is bounded by $z=0$ from below so the question means right. If we count on this surfaces (not planes) and $z=0$, the the following integrals can solve the problem properly:

$$V=2\int_0^{\theta=\pi/2}\int_0^{2\sin\theta}r^2drd\theta$$

[image]

Comment: Green and red: A bit early for Christmas, but, we'll be there in no time at all! +1

Comment: @BabakS.: I agree, nice graphics +1